# Apache Camel and hawt.io debugging: Body/Header not visible at breakpoint

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm currently working with **Apache Camel** and **hawt.io** for monitoring and debugging my Camel routes. This works wonderfully, even if some important information is somewhat hidden in the documentation. For example, it took me a bit to turn on debugging.

However, if I set a **breakpoint** where the **message processing stops** at that point in the route, I **can't see any "body" or "headers"** of my Camel exchange at that point. I've tried all sorts of settings:

- tracing / backlog tracing enabled on CamelContext
- tracing / backlog tracing enabled on route
- Adjusted settings on MBean "BacklogDebugger" and "BacklogTracer".

**Tracing on the "Trace" tab works very well**: If I activate tracing in the "Trace" tab, I can see the flow of my message through all nodes of the route.

Only when stopping at the breakpoint is the body and header not displayed.

---

**Edited**: After some changes concerning other aspects (like assigning an ID to most of the route nodes) debugging works including display of body and headers. I have no clue what changed to make it work.

And at the same time my application property "camel.main.debugging=true" failed on startup

```
Error binding property (camel.main.debugging=true) with name: debugging on bean: org.apache.camel.main.MainConfigurationProperties
```

I had to enabled debugging at the context like this:

```
getContext().setDebugging(true);
```

---

Here is some information:

- I don't use any special framework: Plain old Java with a Main method in which I start Camel-Main.
- Apache Camel: 3.14.1
- Jolokai Agent: 1.7.1
- hawt.io: 2.14.5
- Exchange body type: DOMSource

One of my routes:

```
getCamelContext().setBacklogTracing(true);

from(rabbitMqFactory.queueConnect("tso11", "tso11-to-nms", "username"))
  .routeGroup("Workflow")
  .routeId("Workflow-to-NMS|Map-TSO11-to-NMS42")
  .routeDescription("Mapping of TSO11 Message to NMS42")
  .convertBodyTo(DOMSource.class)
  .log("Message for '$simple{header:tenant}' received")
  .process(tso11ToNmsMappingProcessor)
  .to("xslt:xslt/tso11-to-nms42.xslt")
  .to("direct:send");
```

And here are my current properties:

```
camel.main.name=TSO11
camel.main.jmxEnabled=true
camel.main.debugging=true
camel.main.backlogTracing=true
camel.main.lightweight=false
camel.main.tracing=false
camel.main.useBreadcrumb=true
```

Any ideas? Any hints for a good documentation?

I have some more less important questions but I will open another issue for those.

With kind recards
Bert

---

Finally here are screenhots of **debugging tab** (with empty body) and **trace tab** (with body content):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for my problem:

**I used Camel 3.15.0 which is currently not supported by the camel plugin of hawt.io.
When using latest 3.14.x it works like a charm :-)**

Hopefully there is still a maintainer of the camel plugin who will improve it in the near future. I am willing to contribute but the hawt.io developer information is not accessible and I am not able to understand how to run hawt.io from source locally .... especially how to include the camel plugin, which is in a separate github project.